# How to convert jquery pic zoomer for RTL users

Tags: html, jquery, css, rtlcss

I would like to get jquery plugin for the following code for RTL users. Can someone help me convert this jquery code in RTL.
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Image-Zoom-On-Hover-picZoomer

here is the jquery code. i just need help to get this calculation for RTL users. CSS is RTL ready but tried changing jquery but no results.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.picZoomer = function(options){
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.picZoomer.defaults, options), 
            $this = this,
            $picBD = $('<div class="picZoomer-pic-wp"></div>').css({'width':opts.picWidth+'px', 'height':opts.picHeight+'px'}).appendTo($this),
            $pic = $this.children('img').addClass('picZoomer-pic').appendTo($picBD),
            $cursor = $('<div class="picZoomer-cursor"><i class="f-is picZoomCursor-ico"></i></div>').appendTo($picBD),
            cursorSizeHalf = {w:$cursor.width()/2 ,h:$cursor.height()/2},
            $zoomWP = $('<div class="picZoomer-zoom-wp"><img src="" alt="" class="picZoomer-zoom-pic"></div>').appendTo($this),
            $zoomPic = $zoomWP.find('.picZoomer-zoom-pic'),
            picBDOffset = {x:$picBD.offset().left,y:$picBD.offset().top};

        
        opts.zoomWidth = opts.zoomWidth||opts.picWidth;
        opts.zoomHeight = opts.zoomHeight||opts.picHeight;
        var zoomWPSizeHalf = {w:opts.zoomWidth/2 ,h:opts.zoomHeight/2};

        //初始化zoom容器大小
        $zoomWP.css({'width':opts.zoomWidth+'px', 'height':opts.zoomHeight+'px'});
        $zoomWP.css(opts.zoomerPosition || {top: 0, left: opts.picWidth+30+'px'});
        //初始化zoom图片大小
        $zoomPic.css({'width':opts.picWidth*opts.scale+'px', 'height':opts.picHeight*opts.scale+'px'});

        //初始化事件
        $picBD.on('mouseenter',function(event){
            $cursor.show();
            $zoomWP.show();
            $zoomPic.attr('src',$pic.attr('src'))
        }).on('mouseleave',function(event){
            $cursor.hide();
            $zoomWP.hide();
        }).on('mousemove', function(event){
            var x = event.pageX-picBDOffset.x,
                y = event.pageY-picBDOffset.y;

            $cursor.css({'left':x-cursorSizeHalf.w+'px', 'top':y-cursorSizeHalf.h+'px'});
            $zoomPic.css({'left':-(x*opts.scale-zoomWPSizeHalf.w)+'px', 'top':-(y*opts.scale-zoomWPSizeHalf.h)+'px'});

        });
        return $this;

    };
    $.fn.picZoomer.defaults = {
        picWidth: 320,
        picHeight: 320,
        scale: 2.5,
        zoomerPosition: {top: '0', left: '350px'}
        /*,
        zoomWidth: 320,
        zoomHeight: 320*/
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Reduce your issue and share your code and what you have tried here and we can help.

Comment: edited, please check